# How to Add Choices to database field using GORM

Tags: database, go, go-gorm

I'm very new to Golang as I mostly code in Python, so came across one problem that I'm not able to solve. I want to add choices to a field in Golang Struct via [GORM](https://gorm.io/docs/index.html) or any other way if I can achieve that.

My model looks like this

```
type User struct{
   FirstName string  `gorm:"size:100" json:"first_name"`
   LastName  string  `gorm:"size:100" json:"last_name"`
   Email     *string `gorm:"size:250;index;not null;index:email;unique" json:"email"`
   Role      string  `gorm:"default:User;not null" json:"is_active"` // TODO Add Choice
}
```

I want to add choices to my Role Field in User Models from ['Admin', 'User', 'Guest']. Is there a way to achieve it using GORM or any other method that will solve my problem? I can make it a Foreign key if there is no direct way to do it. I'm using PostgreSQL to store tables. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a one-to-one relation between `roles` and `users`, one approach with the foreign keys would be something like this:

```
type User struct{
   ID        int64 `json:"id"`
   FirstName string  `gorm:"size:100" json:"first_name"`
   LastName  string  `gorm:"size:100" json:"last_name"`
   Email     *string `gorm:"size:250;index;not null;index:email;unique" json:"email"`
   RoleID    int64  `json:"role_id"` 
   Role      *Role `json:"role"`
}

type Role struct {
   ID   int64 `json:"id"`
   Name string `json:"name"`
}

//load data
var users []User
err := db.Preload("Role").Find(&users).Error
```

**EDIT: solution for many-to-many
relationship**

Assuming that you would have a table like `users_roles` that links the `users` and `roles` tables, one solution might look like this:

```
type User struct{
   ID        int64 `json:"id"`
   FirstName string  `gorm:"size:100" json:"first_name"`
   LastName  string  `gorm:"size:100" json:"last_name"`
   Email     *string `gorm:"size:250;index;not null;index:email;unique" json:"email"`
   Roles      []*Role `gorm:"many2many:users_roles;" json:"roles"`
}

type Role struct {
   ID   int64 `json:"id"`
   Name string `json:"name"`
}

//load data
var users []User
err := db.Preload("Roles").Find(&users).Error
```

Comment: Is there a way to define it as a list and directly use it, if i don't want to create another relationship?

Comment: If it indicates a list of restricted values that can be inserted in that specific column, you might want to check out the check constraint https://gorm.io/docs/constraints.html#CHECK-Constraint

Comment: Thanks Emin. Just curious if I want to add more than one values to Role, lets say a user can be a Admin as well as Normal Regular. Is that done by check constraint or something else?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a potential solution for a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 2):

For **PostGreSQL** First create enum manually in your database

```
CREATE TYPE user_access AS ENUM (
    'admin',
    'user'
);
```

Then

```golang
type Role string

const (
    Admin  Role = "admin"
    User   Role = "user"
)

func (r *Role) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    *r = Role(value.([]byte))
    return nil
}

func (r Role) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return string(r), nil
}

type User struct{
   ID        int64   `json:"id"`
   FirstName string  `gorm:"size:100" json:"first_name"`
   LastName  string  `gorm:"size:100" json:"last_name"`
   Email     *string `gorm:"size:250;index;not null;index:email;unique" json:"email"`
   Role      Role    `sql:"type:user_access"` // PostGreSQL
   Role      Role    `json:"role" sql:"type:ENUM('admin', 'user')"` // MySQL
}
```

For more info you can check [github issue](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/1978#issuecomment-476673540) and [doc](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html)

Comment: You should probably include the fact that it's a Postgres-specific solution.